# Output array numbers with their negation in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Given an array of integers. If the number a and its negation -a both present in the array then print it. ex:if {10, 5, 0, 9, -10, 7, -5} is given then print 10, 5.
I gave the interviewer O(N) time and O(N) Space complexity code based on HashMap but he further asked me to reduce the space complexity to O(1) in the worst-case keeping time complexity O(N).
Note: Counting sort was not allowed.
Please, can anyone provide me the O(1) space complexity approach?

Comment: Add a tag to specify what language you want your answer in.  Also add the solution that you have.

Comment: Don't think it is possible

Comment: If the numbers are small, you can use a bitmask to keep track of the items.

Comment: Do the negative values always appear last?

Comment: Is using a binary trie of positive numbers a solution?

Comment: @vivek_23 how is a binary trie for N elements O(1) space?

Comment: Well, the max depth of the tree would just be 31 for integer range elements. Also, the trie is only going to be for positive numbers. When we come across negative elements, we could take absolute value of it and check for its existence in the trie.

Comment: @vivek_23 what about the trie's width? How does the trie identify N items in O(1) space? [As far as I can tell](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/13_1_BinaryTrie_digital_sea.html), space complexity of a binary trie is `O(n*w)`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Trie's width totally depends upon the arrangement of the numbers. Height shouldn't go more than 31 for integer range elements. Anyway, not sure if interviewer  had any solution, or was it just a trick question.

Comment: @vivek_23 Again: how is "height 1" of a trie "the same" as getting to O(1) space?

Comment: @GhostCat Because the height would never go beyond 31 for integers regardless of the size of the array. Not sure about width as I haven't implemented yet, but just a rough idea.

Comment: Maybe the recruiter wanted you to push back that such solution is feasible and explain why?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space if the array elements are unordered and are within an arbitrary range. If the array is sorted, we can solve it within those constraints using two pointers.

Comment: I gave the interviewer same answer but he was not convinced.

Comment: @HarshulAgarwal great. Let's hear his solution, as well as clear input parameters as to ordering and range.